# How to read matrix from stdin in c

Tags: c, matrix

Question is simple how should I save matrix from stdin to 2d array. Problem is that I dont know size and also I should recognize bad input

Example of correct input:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Example of incorrect input:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6 5
7 8 9

1 2 3 4
```

First I try to read value to one dimension array till EOF with scanf and then create with 1d array 2d array. Is this OK ? I dont know how can scanf recognize new line.

Comment: combination of [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets), [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) and [`malloc()`/ `calloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) will solve your  problem.

Comment: You can't really use `scanf` to recognize end of line, it only can recognize whitespace (which includes newlines, tabs and spaces). Instead you might want to use e.g. `fgets` to get a line, and then split that line (using e.g. `strtok`) on space to get the individual values on the line.

Comment: However there's a bigger problem, I think: If you don't know the dimensions of the matrix, how would you know that the first line is correct? Or will the number of values on the first line always tell you the dimensions? Will the dimensions always be NxN, or can it be MxN?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sir, IMO, by _size_ OP meant number of _rows_. Otherwise, this is a conceptual problem rather than a programmatic one, isn't it?

Comment: @Gopi Nothing in the question indicates that it has to be NxN, not even the example of incorrect input. It just tells me that empty lines are not allowed. There's nothing to say that the matrix in the incorrect input is a 4x4 or a 3x3 matrix, or even a 3x4 or 4x3 matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use `fgets()` to read till end of line.
2. Break the line using `strtok()` and space as delimiter
3. Now convert each token to integer using `strtol()`
4. The return value can be stored in the array.
5. Count the number of tokens successfully converted to integers and keep the count
6. Allocate memory based on the count.
7. If the count is zero then there there were no integers and you can gracefully ignore the line.

Use `malloc()` to initially allocate memory to your array and you can increase the size of the array based on the input using `realloc()`

Comment: If the OP wants to know about incorrect input, the OP should probably be using `strtol` instead of `atoi`, as there is no way of knowing if you give wrong input to `atoi`.

Comment: The [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) function have an argument to allow you to distinguish between fully valid input (e.g. `"123"`), partial valid input (e.g. `"123abc"`) or fully invalid input (e.g. `"abc"`). Using `atoi` one can not distinguish between the two first (`"123"` and `"123abc"`) as well as distinguish between invalid and zero (`"abc"` and `"0"`).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm), `scanf` reads a string delimited by whitespace, including new line characters. It should not be necessary to explicitly check for end of line characters. For the task described, it should be sufficient just to read the desired number of elements.

Comment: If at all you're going for `scanf()` i'll ___strongly___ recommend for checking of return value first-hand.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a problem for you, you can read it in 1d array, get matrix size N=sqrt(elementsCount) and in your code access elements like this:

```
array[row*N + col]; //its equivalent of array2d[row][col] from 2d array
```

or you can read it into 1d array, then alloc matrix and copy values here.

also, if newline in stdin always mean new row in matrix, you can read it into 2d array and dynamically reallocating it in the process.

I would recommend first approach

//edit of course, first two solutions works for NxN matrices. If there can be MxN matrix, you need to use third approach

Comment: yea when u are reading 9 number on one line ? Your first solution will think that it is matrix 3x3 what is wrong

Comment: with my first solution you need to read whole input and then calculate matrix size, so lines doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I try to do it with gopl sollution. I miss some validation against size and use some constant because now I dont care about allocation. Important is just reading from stdin. So is this correct solution how to read matrix from stdin line by line which end EOF

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 10000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    char * pch;
    int matrix[25][25];
    int row = 0, column = 0;

    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    printf("Enter a matrix: \n");
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
        pch = strtok(buffer, " ");
        column = 0;

        while (pch != NULL) {
            int li1 = strtol(pch, NULL, 10);
            pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
            matrix[row][column] = li1;
            column++;
        }
        row++;
    }
    printf("Number: %dvs%d\n", row, column);
    return 0;
}
```